# Access public assets with Java in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, assets

Is it possible to access `Assets` inside the Java code in `Play Framework`? How?

We access assets from the scala HTML templates this way:

```
<img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/myimage.png")" width="800" />
```

But I could not find any documentation nor code example to do it from inside the Java code. I just found a `controllers.Assets` class but it is unclear how to use it. If this is the class that has to be used, should it maybe be injected?

Comment: Do you want you to use JAVA in the HTML files?

Comment: No, I just want to load an image from the Asset folder inside my Java code. This was just an example to show how we access it in scala.

Comment: Did anyone ever find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to access the public folder even from a production mode application.
In order to be accessible/copied in the distributed version, public folder need to be mapped that way in build.sbt:

```
import NativePackagerHelper._
mappings in Universal ++= directory("public")
```

The files are then accessible in the public folder in the distributed app in production form the Java code:

```
  private static final String PUBLIC_IMAGE_DIRECTORY_RELATIVE_PATH = "public/images/";

  static File getImageAsset(String relativePath) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
     final String path = PUBLIC_IMAGE_DIRECTORY_RELATIVE_PATH + relativePath;
     final File file = new File(path);
     if (!file.exists()) {
       throw new ResourceNotFoundException(String.format("Asset %s not found", path));
     }
     return file;
  }
```

This post put me on the right way to find the solution: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/sVDoEtAzP-U

Answer (score 0):

The assets normally are in the "public" folder, and I don't know how you want to use your image so I have used `ImageIO` .

```
File file = new File("./public/images/nice.png");
boolean exists = file.exists();
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
try {
    ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.read(file); //Use it
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("EX = "+exists+" - "+absolutePath);
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this but couldn't access the folder in production as the app was not packaged the same way when distributed. Finally found a way to include the public folder in the distribution package.